# Is it possible to push from git server to a client?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

When I push changes to Git server, I want it push the whole repository to other machines.

`[My machine]---- push ---->[git server]---- push ---->[Machine A]
                                   +------- push ---->[Machine B]`

I use `hooks` to get notified when somebody checks in and that works but I have no idea how to push from the server to other machines. I read [Git Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows) (just the basic workflow) but there was nothing that help me.

Is it possible to do this? What are commands or keywords I should use to google?

Comment: Are Machine A, Machine B, etc. servers or client machines? It's likely a very bad idea to push code to other developers without their cooperation. Depending on how you set this up you could cause conflicts (very likely), or even overwrite other developers' changes.

Comment: Git doesn't really follow a "client-server" model, it's more "peer-to-peer". As far as Git is concerned you just have repositories on different machines. If you can connect from the "git server" machine to "Machine A" over a Git transport configured to accept writes to the repository then you can "push" to it but that's sort of a circular definition.

Answer (score 2):

First, this not the usual way of using git or deploying applications to servers. For deployment there are special tools like `capistrano` for ruby on rails or the `capifony` extensions for symfony. Sure there are many more for other purposes.

---

However, what you asked can be done with git too, even if it is hackish.

First you need a clone of the repo on `Machine A` and `Machine B` and you need ssh access to that machines from `git server`.

On `git server` add those remotes:

```
git remote add MachineA user@MachineA:/path/to/repository.git
git remote add MachineB user@MachineB:/path/to/repository.git
```

Then you can push using this commands:

```
git push MachineA master
git push MachineB master
```

And ... Boom! You get an error:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
```

This is because the remote repositories in this case aren't bare repositories. Normally non-bare repositories are meant for development. If somebody would push into such repo it would override the current state of development there and therefore git denies this (thx git). In your case they are not meant for development, so you can issue the following command in both remote repositories to get rid of the problem:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

The push will now work but if you enter the remote server you'll see that the files aren't changed there. This is another protection of git, it doesn't overwrite the local files. To achieve this you need to issue:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

on the remote repositories. This can be automated using a `post-receive` hook there:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Now it should work as expected. (Although this is not the "usual" way of using git)

---

To avoid entering the password manually you'll need some passwordless authentication. But note that a hacker that can access `git server` would have passwordless access to those machines too. Therefore `user` on those machines should be as restricted as possible.